# XML-RPC ResponseError failures on some machines and not others

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, xmlrpclib, moinmoin

I have a very simple python script that connects to a MoinMoin wiki via XMLRPC (v2) and pulls some data. It all begins with a simple authentication:

```
self._server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(self.url)
self.token = self._server.getAuthToken(self.user, self.password)
```

The same script works on some machines, and fails on others.
Below are the error dumps, and at the bottom the Apache logs.

It works on this machine:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
```

But it fails on this machine (notice same python version):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
[...]
    self.token = self._server.getAuthToken(self.user, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 791, in close
    raise ResponseError()
xmlrpclib.ResponseError: ResponseError()
```

It also fails on this machine (same error, different line numbers obviously):

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Sep 26 2013, 18:48:04) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
[...]
   self.token = self._server.getAuthToken(self.user, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1199, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1489, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1253, in request
    return self._parse_response(h.getfile(), sock)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1392, in _parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 836, in close
    raise ResponseError()
xmlrpclib.ResponseError: ResponseError()
```

MoinMoin server details:

```
Python Version
    2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:09:21) [GCC 4.6.3]
MoinMoin Version
    Release 1.9.7 [Revision release]
```

Here's the apache log (captured later, so it might not be related; I haven't tried a cross-correlation with the time):

```
[Wed Apr 02 00:20:15 2014] [error] 2014-04-02 00:20:15,212 INFO MoinMoin.config.multiconfig:127 using wiki config: /opt/moin/share/moin/wikiconfig.pyc
[Wed Apr 02 00:23:35 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=4909): Maximum requests reached 'moin'.
[Wed Apr 02 00:23:35 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=4909): Shutdown requested 'moin'.
[Wed Apr 02 00:23:35 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=4909): Stopping process 'moin'.
[Wed Apr 02 00:23:35 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=4909): Destroying interpreters.
[Wed Apr 02 00:23:35 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=4909): Destroy interpreter 'foo.bar.baz|'.
[Wed Apr 02 00:23:35 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=4909): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Wed Apr 02 00:23:35 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=4909): Terminating Python.
[Wed Apr 02 00:23:35 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=4909): Python has shutdown.
[Wed Apr 02 00:23:35 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=10496): Attach interpreter ''.
```

Any clue? I'm really flabbergasted.

Comment: A ResponseError would arise when the URL you targeted for the request on the server didn't actually respond with a valid XML-RPC response payload but something else. Try using wireshark or snoop to see what the response actually contained. It is possibly some normal HTML page response.

Answer (score 0):

Use a keyword search in the server configuration files to troubleshoot by looking for access control restrictions based on IP or hostnames:

- Apache: `Allow from` or `Deny from`
- nginx: `allow` or `deny`
- Lighttpd: `$HTTP["host"]` or `$HTTP["remoteip"]`

**References**

- [mod_access_compat - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html)
- [nginx Docs: Module ngx_http_access_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html)
- [Docs Configuration: Conditional Configuration - Lighttpd - lighty labs](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration#Conditional-Configuration)

Comment: It has been so long that I forgot what the problem was or how (if!) I even solved it. Thanks for the answer anyway.